# Crossings in the $p$-$V$-diagram of Thermodynamic cycles

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, volume

Today I was tasked with correcting and grading a first year thermodynamics exam and one student drew a very peculiar diagram for the Ericsson-cycle. In the p-V-diagram the isothermal expansion and isothermal compression crossed. Now this is obviously wrong for the Ericcson-cycle, but can there be a thermodynamic cycle with crossings in the p-V-diagram? Is there a deeper reason why an internet search won't reveal any examples?

Comment: Do you mean cross and continue on, or do you mean intersect and terminate at the point of intersection?

Answer (score 4):

There is no physical reason why a cycle cannot cross in the diagram p-V diagram. However, there are practical reasons not to do that. Remember that the work done by the system in a cycle is the area inside the cycle in the p-v diagram. If a line cross, and you have something like a deformed eight (or two lobes), in one of the lobes the work will be positive but in the other it will be negative. You have both, a heating engine and a refrigerator in series. The cycle will be more efficient if you only keep one of the lobes instead.

[image]

Comment: This is true in the case of a figure eight, but you could also have a cycle that crosses itself but where the work is positive in both subcycles.

Comment: @EliasRiedelGårding True, I missed that.